# importxml xpath query for specific information on a table without name

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to extract data from a table on a website onto a google spreadsheet but don't know how to extract the specific information:

This is the website address:  http://www.zabihah.com/c/Birmingham+12

I want to copy the Restaurant name, cuisine, and address starting from Little Island Cafe to In-N-Out Grill into separate columns on google spreadsheet.

I have tried various permutations of importxml function but have not been successful.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What did you try so far? Please post, for example, one of your unsuccessful use of `importxml`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula to get you started

in cell A1

```
=transpose(
  ImportXML(
    "http://www.zabihah.com/c/Birmingham+12";
    "//div[@class='subtitleLink']//b"
   )
 )
```

along with this link to help you gain a better understanding of [Xpath, html attributes and tags](http://www.distilled.net/blog/distilled/guide-to-google-docs-importxml/).